# Plot the positive infinity symbol and negative infinity symbol

Tags: r, plot, plotmath

I was wondering how I can plot the positive infinity sign and -Infinity sign in plot?

Here is my R code (with no success):

```
plot(1, ty ='n', ann = F, xlim = c(-4, 6), ylim = c(-3.5, 1.5) )

text(c(-4, 6 ), rep(1, 2), c( bquote(- infinity  ), bquote(infinity  ) ) )
```

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, and found your question interesting, how you tried running two separate `text()`?

Comment: @user138773, thanks yes but I wanted to keep my codes short. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Per `?plotmath`, use `expression` instead of `bquote`: `text(c(-4, 6 ), rep(1, 2), c( expression(-infinity), expression(infinity) ) ) `

Comment: `text(c(-4, 6 ), rep(1, 2), c( expression(-infinity  ), bquote(infinity  ) ) )` succeeds. The first item given to `c` must be a true R-expression-classed item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
text(c(-4, 6 ), rep(1, 2), c( bquote("- \U221E"), bquote("\U221E") ) )
```

Comment: No need for `bquote`.

Comment: You are right. I just unthinkingly modified the OP's command. Better without the bquote.

Comment: The success of this will depend on the font in use. It is naot as "safe" as the answer that uses `expression(.)`

Answer (score 8):

`?plotmath` starts

> If the `text` argument to one of the text-drawing functions (`text`,
>   `mtext`, `axis`, `legend`) in R is an **expression**, the argument is
>   interpreted as a mathematical expression and the output will be
>   formatted according to TeX-like rules.

and the `labels` parameter of `text` is documented as

> a character vector or **expression** specifying the *text* to be written. An
>   attempt is made to coerce other language objects (names and calls) to
>   expressions, and vectors and other classed objects to character
>   vectors by `as.character`.

(emphasis mine). `bquote` does not actually return an expression (the R class, not the concept), but a language object (a call, specifically). This is causing two problems:

- Because R can't handle a vector of calls, `c` does not actually create a vector, but instead coerces the result to a list, akin to how `c(sum, mean)` is coerced to a list, and
- While `text` would coerce the call returned from `bquote` itself to an expression (which would get parsed properly), it coerces the list to a character vector, which does not get interpreted according to `plotmath`.

You could coerce the list of calls produced with `c` and `bquote` explicitly with `as.expression`, but it's quicker to just call `expression` directly and avoid `bquote` altogether:

```
plot(1, ty ='n', ann = F, xlim = c(-4, 6), ylim = c(-3.5, 1.5))

text(c(-4, 6 ), rep(1, 2), expression(-infinity, infinity))
```

[image: plot with infinity symbols]

As an end note, `c` actually *does* work on multiple expressions—sort of—in that `c(expression(-infinity), expression(infinity))` returns `expression(-infinity, infinity)`. Unlike `bquote`, which has two named parameters, `expression` takes `...` though, so it's easier to just call it once with multiple inputs.